# System unstable after 5.13.0-40 update to 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: nvidia

I have been very happy with my Ubuntu 20.04.4LTS system until a few days ago when I installed the 5.13.0-40 update. When installing this update the installation process seemed to freeze removing an earlier update (cant recall which one). I waited an hour to see if it would complete but no change so forced a shutdown and reboot. System rebooted running the -40 update but was variously unstable. It might hang on the Ubuntu boot screen with the spinning wheel thing, or may go further but just freeze a short time later. Booting into the -39 kernel from the grub menus works fine, system stable as expected. Booting the -40 the same way gives same problems.

Basic system
Dual boot, Ubuntu and W10,
ASUS ROG STRIX Z690-A GAMING WIFI D4 LGA 1700 ATX Motherboard,
Intel Core i7-12700K 12 Core,
Corsair Vengeance RGB PRO 32GB (2x 16GB) DDR4 3600MHz CL18 Memory,
2x Seagate FireCuda 530 1TB PCI-Express Gen4x4 NVMe M.2 2280-D2 SSD (one for Ubuntu, one for W10),
ASUS GeForce RTX 3080 TUF Gaming OC V2 10GB Video Card - LHR Version,
LG UltraGear 34in UWQHD IPS 165Hz G-Sync Compatible FreeSync Curved Gaming Monitor (34GN850-B),
Corsair Keyboard.

Any help debugging would be very much appreciated. Will gladly run any commands and supply output to assist in diagnosis.

Peter

Thank you Joepie Es for your assistance.

I altered grub to boot the -39 system. Then followed your instructions (with a little edit to add the "-generic" to packages I was removing. This left me with a single function version of the system, -39 which boots and runs without problems.

Where to now? Do I just cut my losses and wait for the next update, or do I bother to try and get -40 correct? Is there a simple "kick off the failed update for a second try" command?

Peter

Below are the commands I executed:

```
$ sudo dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-27-generic              5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-43-generic              5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-44-generic              5.11.0-44.48~20.04.2                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic              5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic              5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic              5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-28-generic              5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic              5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-35-generic              5.13.0-35.40~20.04.1                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-37-generic              5.13.0-37.42~20.04.1                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic              5.13.0-39.44~20.04.1                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic              5.13.0-40.45~20.04.1                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04              5.13.0.40.45~20.04.25               amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Then

```
$ uname -r
5.13.0-39-generic
```

Then

```
$ sudo apt purge linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic  linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic  linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  amd64-microcode intel-microcode iucode-tool linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-40 thermald
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-generic-hwe-20.04* linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic* linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04* linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic*
  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04* linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic* linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-40-generic*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 7 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 432 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 296137 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-generic-hwe-20.04 (5.13.0.40.45~20.04.25) ...
Removing linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 (5.13.0.40.45~20.04.25) ...
Removing linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic (5.13.0-40.45~20.04.1) ...
Removing linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 (5.13.0.40.45~20.04.25) ...
Removing linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-40-generic (5.13.0-40.45~20.04.1) ...
Removing linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic (5.13.0-40.45~20.04.1) ...
Removing linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic (5.13.0-40.45~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms:
dkms: removing: nvidia 510.60.02 (5.13.0-40-generic) (x86_64)

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  nvidia
Version: 510.60.02
Kernel:  5.13.0-40-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

nvidia.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.13.0-40-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-modeset.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.13.0-40-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-drm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.13.0-40-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-uvm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.13.0-40-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-peermem.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.13.0-40-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.13.0-39-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.13.0-39-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-39-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
(Reading database ... 279632 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-40-generic (5.13.0-40.45~20.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic (5.13.0-40.45~20.04.1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic, directory '/lib/modules/5.13.0-40-generic' not empty so not removed
Purging configuration files for linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic (5.13.0-40.45~20.04.1) ...
rmdir: failed to remove '/lib/modules/5.13.0-40-generic': Directory not empty

(the /lib/modules/5.13.0-40-generic/misc directory contained 3 virtualbox files that were also contained in the -39-generic/misc directory
so I removed the non empty directory tree from and including /lib/modules/5.13.0-40-generic )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list of installed kernels. Use `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` in the terminal. 
Check what current kernel you run with the command:`uname -r`
If you did what I wrote before you will run 5.13.0-39 now.
Uninstall the 5.13.0-40 kernel with:
 `sudo apt purge linux-headers-5.13.0-40  linux-image-5.13.0-40  linux-modules-5.13.0-40`.
You can also use 'Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer' (

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

)if you don't have that installed, for a more GUI kind of way. This is really easy to use. You see which kernels are installed and which is running now.
Your system would run alright now. So now try the upgrade again. Using the terminal or Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer is up to you. 
Hope that nothing else broke during the 'old' update and also hope this helped you out.

Comment: Hi Joepie ES, I have edited my original post to reflect what I have done, with an additional question to the effect of "where to from here?". Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can try to install the 5.13.0-40 kernel again, or if you want to have 2 working kernels (to be sure) get the 5.13.0-37 kernel first. (Easiest way is with Mainline, see answer above.) But there is no absolute need to get that -40 kernel, as your system is stable with the -39.

Comment: Yes you are right. The 'generic' I forgot to add. Like mentioned above there is no absolute need to run the -40 kernel. It is not like an antivirus program in Windows that you need to update for security reasons. Glad that my anwers helped you. If you like it, please accept it by clicking the V shaped sign.

Comment: To be honest I forgot to add the generic part too, when editing. I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I have since spent some time comparing logs between the -39 and -40 systems and the glaring problem with the -40 is a kernel Oops when trying to configure the iwlwifi for my motherboard. Why it crashes on the -40 kernel and not the -39 I dont know but you all get a big tick for your help. I will raise a bug report through the normal channels and hope that later updates solve the problem. Another option is to turn off wifi and bluetooth in the bios as I use a wired connection anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To run your 5.13.0-39 kernel as standard you can edit /etc/default/grub with your favorite text editor, ie

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Locate the line

GRUB_DEFAULT=0

Change it to the line you want to boot from default, to see which line you want press the key Shift right after your computer computer's POST and keep it pressed, Grub will show the lines available to boot, the fist one is 0, the 2nd one is 1, etc. Insert the value you want in GRUB_DEFAULT=.
If you are more a GUI kind of guy install Grub Customizer.
This PPA contains the latest release of Grub Customizer.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Once installed, run it and select Preferences. In the 'General'-tab there is an option for defaults. Select the one you want. Save changes when done.

Comment: this does not answer the question, which is about *how to get the install to be stable with the -40 kernel*. grub *does* boot it by default, and I assume if the OP updated his system he wants it updated and working, rather than reverting updates.

Comment: First you need a stable system. Remove the damage and after that you can try and upgrade again. Since OP doesn ´t remember why it froze ('seemed to freeze removing an earlier update (cant recall which one)') it is difficult to say. And of course grub tries to boot the latest kernel by default. And that one is giving troubles.

Comment: maybe explain in your answer what steps to take in order to fix the system once it's booted with the old kernel then.

Comment: Got to work now. Now I have no time. Later I will.

Comment: @Esther What OP wants to do is up to him. If he wants to try and upgrade the kernel again he can. Could go smooth, could go wrong. To know that you got to try. He can also choose to keep a stable system and call it a day. For all I know he installs a 5.16 mainline kernel. Again that is up to Daddad, and no one else.